# Comparing two operations/algorithms (A and B) and determining which one is slower of the two

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, computer-science, operation

I'm not asking for the answer, but simply just some guidance on how to carry out the following question...

" Algorithm A requires 5n^2 + 10 operations and Algorithm B requires n^2 + 10n operations. Which is the slower of the algorithms and can you conclude about the time requirements for the two algorithms when n is small and when n is large? "

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Assume `n=1` - calculate. Try again with `n=10`, `n=100`, `n=1000`. See how the result changes. Make a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

A first reaction could be to draw the two functions.

There are online tools for this, so pick one [like here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2x5pf3sihq):

[image]

It looks like for all positive *x*:

5x<sup>2</sup> + 10 > x<sup>2</sup> + 10x

So then the second reaction could be to prove that first impression with basic mathematics:

5x<sup>2</sup> + 10 > x<sup>2</sup> + 10x

⇔ 4x<sup>2</sup> - 10x + 10 > 0

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) for the equality is negative, so there are no *x* for which:

4x<sup>2</sup> - 10x + 10 = 0

And as for x=0 the earlier inequality holds, it holds for all x (even negative, but that is irrelevant).

With this information you can make statements about relative speed of the two algorithms.